# Admin CSS missing from hosted site

Tags: control-panel, css

The development site works locally, but on a live hosted server the admin CSS is missing. The admin JS shows up. The public-facing site works fine on the live server and I can log in to the admin area, but with the admin CSS missing, the admin area is nearly useless. A few potentially useful pieces of information:

- I followed the Craft "Troubleshooting Missing CSS/JS in the Control Panel" instructions  and verified that zlib.output_compression is disabled.
- The generated CSS links from the admin area look like they should work, especially since the JS links do work.
- I'm running PHP 7.0.0 locally, using MAMP.
- The hosting company, Nexcess, is running PHP 7.0.6 on my account.

I'm stumped as to why this is happening or how to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single line in my `gitignore` file, `CSS` was preventing the Admin CSS from deploying to the live server. While this problem isn't specific to Craft, I'm leaving it here in case others encounter the issue.

That line only prevented *folders* named CSS from deploying, which is why the public site CSS deployed without a problem, making the problem less obvious.